# Fully specialized overloaded method is not called when used as template default parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'd like to be able to specify default non-type template parameter by calling one of overloaded fuctions (that are template with full specialization). Following code represents the problem: I expecet `FieldType2 getDefaultField<FieldType2>()` to be printed, but `Called getDefaultField() !` is printed.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class FieldType1 {
    Description1,
    Description2,
    Description3
};

enum class FieldType2 {
    Description1,
    Description2,
    Description3
};

template<class FiledType>
struct FieldDescription {
    constexpr static int startPos{0};
    constexpr static FieldType fieldType{}; 
};

struct ConcreteField2 : public FieldDescription<FieldType2> {};

template<class FieldType>
constexpr FieldType getDefaultField() {
    return FieldType{};
};

template<>
constexpr FieldType1 getDefaultField<FieldType1>() {
    return FieldType1::Description1;
};

template<>
constexpr FieldType2 getDefaultField<FieldType2>() {
    return FieldType2::Description3;
};

template<class FieldDescr,
        decltype(FieldDescr::fieldType) fieldType = getDefaultField<decltype(FieldDescr::fieldType)>()>
void process() {
    if (fieldType == FieldType2::Description3) {
        std::cout << "FieldType2 getDefaultField<FieldType2>()" << std::endl;
    }
    if (fieldType == FieldType2::Description1) {
        std::cout << "Called getDefaultField() !" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    process<ConcreteField2>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use something like `using fieldType = FieldType;` in `FieldDescription` to get the actual *type* of the enumeration, instead of using an otherwise unused member variable. Then you would not need those `decltype` for the `process` template.

Comment: Thanks! That's more elegant and happens to solve my problem. But why the behavioiur is different in my aproach?

Comment: Why Not Specialize Function Templates? = http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype(FieldDescr::fieldType)` is `const FieldType2` not `FieldType2`. So your  specialisation doesn't match and primary template is used.

You might use `std::decay_t`:

```
getDefaultField<std::decay_t<decltype(FieldDescr::fieldType)>>()
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/502e7266954126f3)

But as suggested in comment, that usage of dummy member is strange, a regular `using type = FiledType;` is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest don't use `decltype` and `decay_t` and use `using` to alias `FieldType` instead:

```
template<class FT>
struct FieldDescription {
    using FieldType = FT;
    constexpr static int startPos{0};
    // constexpr static FieldType fieldType{}; // You can get rid of that member,
                                               // unless used elsewhere
};
```

and

```
template <class FieldDescr,
         typename FieldDescr::FieldType fieldType =
             getDefaultField<typename FieldDescr::FieldType>()>
```